# Full size popup when address bar is showing and not showing - mobile chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My popup is supposed to be full screen height minus the header.

However, when the address bar is not showing up (after scrolling down), the space is left blank.

```
var currencyHeight = $(window).innerHeight() - headerHeight;
```

`$(window).innerHeight()` returns 559 both when the address bar is showing and not showing. When it is showing, the popup works fine, full screen minus the header:

[image]

but when it is not showing up you can see the empty space:

[image]

How do people usually solve this?

**Minimal example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/zzuxvg4p/4/

But because jsfiddle uses an iframe, you cannot test it on android properly, so this page has the code from that jsfiddle:

https://annotated-dev.limebuild.net/media/test.html (click on the blue box in the footer. If the address bar isn't showing then the black box is not full screen, but if it is showing then it is full screen).

Here is the issue even after I add the no-scroll class to body with overflow hidden:
[image]

Comment: From what you describe, you are using a hiding method for the header which does not affect its actual `height`. Therefore, even when its hidden, it deducts the same from window height. This is true for hiding elements with `transform`s (because `transform` only affects painting of element, but element remains untouched, occupying the exact same space in its current flow). But these are suppositions. Without a [mcve] it's impossible to tell for sure. Let's save guessing as our last option and rely on actual code.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu thanks for your interest in my question, I updated the question with a replicable example.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I don't think it has anything related with the header height. Because if I scroll up a pixel then the address bar shows and then the popup is full screen. In my example I removed the header logic and the issue is still there.

Comment: Place/remove a class on `<body>` on opening/closing the popup. This class should add `overflow:hidden;` to `<body>`. So you probably want to name it `no-scroll` or similar. Should fix your problem. Also, you won't need to `scrollTop()` anymore. To disable the hiding of top bar on Chrome on Android you a need wrapper div with `height:100vh; overflow: auto`. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu still the same issue if I add it, I updated the question with the image. In a way it is logic because that address bar has some space. it is the .innerHeight which should return different values based on address bar showing or not showing...

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga You can listen to window.resize event and correct the height of the pop up again

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga are you sure about this "$(window).innerHeight() returns 559 both" when I tried window.innerHeight on resize event in android phone the values changed depending on the addressbar presense

Comment: @karthick I'm not sure I follow. The height of the popup is set when I click on the link. At that moment, it always returns 559 even if it has or not the address bar.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga : Can you try window.innerHeight instead of $(window).innerHeight()

Comment: it looks like a bug in jquery. When I tried window.innerHeight onresize it gives the correct height but $(window).innerHeight() return the initial height

Comment: @karthick yes, that does it. different values. I'll have to change the logic of my popup to set the height before clicking on the link. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try window.innerHeight for some reason $(window).innerHeight() returns the samevalue on resize event in android portrait mode.

Jquery Issue
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/764

It looks like its not only Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the exact same issue. Here's what to look out for.

touch-action: none; or
touchAction: none; or
webkit-user-drag: none;

window.innerHeight gives you the height of your window. Let's say 560px with address bar and when the address bar disappears, it'll be 620px. So the height changes when the address bar appears or disappears.

On Chrome, on Android (7.0) (the one I've encountered the issue on) it works until this happens:

if you have "touchAction: none" somewhere (and you do), when you drag with the finger on your screen, the functionality breaks. I do the same thing, I use hammer.js

When I load the page, it works fine. If you add a listener:

```
$('body').append('<div id="follow" style="position: fixed; width: 100px; height: 30px; top: 10px; left: 10px; color: #FFF;"></div>');
$(window).on('resize', function() {
     $('#follow').text(window.innerHeight());
});
```

Copy this code on your page and test it out. The height displayed should change as the address bar appears or disappears. For me, it worked perfect. When opening a full screen modal (like the one you open), a plugin (hammer.js) added touchAction: none;

It's not until you actually touch the screen and drag your finger on it that the functionality breaks. I have a close button at the top-right corner to close the modal. Pressing it removes it and, because I didn't swipe, the functionality does not break.

So if the modal opens and you do add touch-action: none; it won't break. you can close it and, thus, remove the styling (let's say you have)

```
$('#your_modal')[0].style = '';
```

Doing this removes the touch-action css from your element, and window.innerHeight works as intended.

I know what you're thinking. I'm gonna remove it and the functionality should return back to normal. Wrong. Once you touch and swipe on the screen with any div having touch-action: none; the functionality is permanently broken until you refresh the page. You can remove the div, add touch-action: element, auto, whatever, the window.innerHeight will remain stuck at the value it got when you started swiping.

So to fix it i added

```
window.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {

    if (modal_open)
    {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }

}, { passive: false })
```

make sure it's set to passive: false, otherwise you'll get an error.

If you have a script that adds the touch-action: none;, just add

```
$('#whatever')[0].style['touchAction'] = 'auto';
$('#whatever')[0].style['-webkit-user-drag'] = 'auto';
```

after it initializes and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to figure this one out. Starting from scratch, here's what I came up with, tested on android and it does disable top bar from hiding:

```js
var resizer = function(){
  $("html, body, #wrapper").css({
    height: $(window).height()
  });
}, openPopup = function(){
   $('.popup').addClass('open');
}, closePopup = function(){
   $('.popup').removeClass('open');
};

$(window).on('load resize',resizer);
$('.trigger').on('click tap', openPopup);
$('.popup').on('click tap', closePopup);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body #wrapper {
  overflow-y: auto;
  color: white;
}

body #wrapper div {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.test {
  min-height: 150vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.trigger {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 10em;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform .6s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.popup.open {
  transform: translateY(0);
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="test"> I'd be the test</div>
  <div class="trigger">I'd open the popup</div>
  <div class="popup">I'd be the popup</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. That's just my method of choice for controlling the animation when doing this type of slide. It's the fact that `overflow` (scrollbar) is moved from `<body>` to `#wrapper`. Your page now is no longer overflowing, but contains a div with `overflow:auto` or `scroll` - as you prefer. I usually set it to auto. If you let `<body>` scrollable, you can't control the display of the top bar - it's done by the browser, at a level you don't have access to. If you make your fixed div 100% without the bar, when the browser will decide to show the bar, you need to update height of fixed div.